# Error: The version string '${noSnapshotVersion}' is invalid

Tags: alfresco

I'm following the tutorial of Jeff Potts and I'm stick on second part when I'm tring to start the repo project to test new share aspects and types with command ([here](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/content/tutorial/tutorial.html#step-3-test-your-changes))

```
mvn integration-test -Pamp-to-war
```

This is the output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building content-tutorial-repo AMP project
[INFO] task-segment: [integration-test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [alfresco:set-version {execution: default-set-version}]
[INFO] Removed -SNAPSHOT suffix from version - 1.0
[INFO] Added timestamp to version - 1.0.1406090928
[INFO] [build-helper:add-test-resource {execution: add-env-test-properties}]
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/mattia/workspace/AlfrescoTutorial/content-tutorial-repo/src/main/resources
[INFO] Copying 10 resources to ../content-tutorial-repo
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] [resources:copy-resources {execution: prepare-amp-testing-classpath}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] [dependency:unpack {execution: unpack-alfresco}]
[INFO] Configured Artifact: org.alfresco:alfresco:4.2.e:war
[INFO] alfresco-4.2.e.war already unpacked.
[INFO] [resources:copy-resources {execution: copy-alfresco-test-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/xxx/workspace/AlfrescoTutorial/content-tutorial-repo/src/test/webapp
[INFO] Copying 7 resources to WEB-INF/classes
[INFO] Copying 1 resource to WEB-INF/classes
[INFO] [resources:copy-resources {execution: copy-tomcat-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource to WEB-INF
[INFO] [alfresco:amp {execution: default-amp}]
[INFO] Building jar: /home/mattia/workspace/AlfrescoTutorial/content-tutorial-    repo/target/content-tutorial-repo/lib/content-tutorial-repo.jar
[INFO] Adding directory to AMP package [ '/home/mattia/workspace/AlfrescoTutorial/content-tutorial-repo/target/content-tutorial-repo' '']
[INFO] Building amp: /home/mattia/workspace/AlfrescoTutorial/content-tutorial-repo/target/content-tutorial-repo.amp
[INFO] [alfresco:install {execution: amps-to-war-overlay}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 05090000 The version string '${noSnapshotVersion}' is invalid.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 05090000 The version string  
'${noSnapshotVersion}' is invalid.
at org.alfresco.util.VersionNumber.(VersionNumber.java:80)
at org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleDetailsImpl.(ModuleDetailsImpl.java:137)
at org.alfresco.repo.module.tool.ModuleDetailsHelper.
    createModuleDetailsFromPropertiesStream(ModuleDetailsHelper.java:53)
at  org.alfresco.repo.module.tool.ModuleDetailsHelper.
    createModuleDetailsFromPropertyLocation(ModuleDetailsHelper.java:83)
at org.alfresco.repo.module.tool.ModuleManagementTool.
    installModule(ModuleManagementTool.java:227)
at org.alfresco.maven.plugin.InstallMojo.execute(InstallMojo.java:110)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.
    executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.
    executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.
    executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.
    executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.
    executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.
    executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.
    execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jun 09 09:28:22 CEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 63M/713M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please can you give me any hint on how make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Maven version.

I had that problem and fixed it updating to the lastest version.

At the time, I was using the Ubuntu pa

Comment: Thak you! It goes on now, but I get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space... how can I increase permgen size? Don't know where maven stores tomcat.

Comment: Try setting an environment variable like MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx1G -XX:PermSize=300m". You may need to tweak these settings based on your environment but another user reported that these worked for him.